# WP/WooCommerce multisite with polylang, product duplication between websites

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite, plugin-polylang

I am looking for a way to duplicate products between multisite websites with one of the websites working as a master for product management (this is no the main site but one of the subsites). The duplication doesn't need to be automatic or rather would be preferred if it's manually triggered, so when you update a single product (or multiple products) you could update that/them to a specific subsite or mainsite.

One thing that I have had problems is the compatibility with polylang. The multisite is using WordPress plugin Polylang to make the websites multilingual and the product duplication would also need to support this (as in the duplication identifies also the language to which to copy).

If you have any experience/suggestions with plugins that support this kind of behaviour or same kind of multisite cases, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.